# Jasper Reports Refresh

Tags: java, report, refresh

I created an GUI with a few buttons, that connects to an access database, saves data, and has a few buttons including 2 buttons which open two Jasper Reports. It works fine except that it doesn't refresh. I noticed that the report has a refresh button but It's disabled. I need a solution that doesn't involve the close and reopen the report in order to refresh data the report gets from the Access database.

If there is any way that I could add some autorefresh that executes every minute that would be even better.

I resumed the code to only to one button to make it simpler. The Flights class contains the concection the database.

```
public class FlightsGui extends Flights {

 JButton departuresReport = new JButton("Departures Report");

 public FlightsGui() {
        frame();
        btnAction();
}

public void frame()
    {


          f = new JFrame();


        f.setSize(700,500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(p,BorderLayout.NORTH);
         GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

         p.add(departuresReport); 

}


 public void btnAction()
    {

 departuresReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try{


         String departuresRep = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Flights\\src\\Fights\\report1.jrxml\\";

            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(departuresRep );
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,con);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);


                }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}
            }


            }  


                    ); } }
```

Comment: If you are referring to refreshing the view of the .jrxml you can check out some of the timers, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html since you may also want to repaint the data.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) A single blank line of white space is always enough.   3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).